# Dynamically render style sheet from useEffect?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use a button (passed to another component) to toggle a dark mode. Initially, I load a light-theme stylesheet. Then, the toggle theme button should remove the latest loaded stylesheet on the page and set the state to the opposite of the current state.

My understanding was that, then, useEffect would 'see' the state change and kick in. That's where we load the new style sheet. The app loads the initial style sheet correctly, and the toggle button works correctly once, but not after that. After the first change, it removes all styles. With the react dev-tools, it looks like state is updating correctly. I think my understanding of useEffect and/or useState is wrong. Any pointers or help is appreciated!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navi from "./Components/Layout/Navi";
import Price from "./Components/Price";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import About from "./Components/About/About";
require("bootswatch/dist/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css");

function App() {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");
    const toggleTheme = () => {
        Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("style")).slice(-1)[0].remove();
        setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark");
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("fire");
        console.log(theme);
        if (theme === "light") {
            require("bootswatch/dist/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css");
        } else if (theme === "dark") {
            require("bootswatch/dist/slate/bootstrap.min.css");
        } else {
            console.log("Theme state not correctly set");
        }
    });
    return (
        <Router path="/">
            <>
                <div className="App">
                    <Navi toggleTheme={() => toggleTheme()} />
                    <Container>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Price} />
                        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
                    </Container>
                </div>
            </>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `useEffect` seems to be accurate. They are executing when you expect them to. What's not happening as you expect is the `import`.

When you `require` a css file it adds an `html` tag to your dom.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/overrides.css">
```

`require`ing another CSS file doesn't undo the `require` that has occurred - it's still being added to your browser stylesheet. You can think of it as the same as importing a JS file rather than rendering a component.

### Option 1: Add your own `<style>` tag

Your most direct option is to import both files as strings, then apply the desired styles in a `<style>` tag. It's the "quick and easy" option, but includes some tradeoffs (e.g. you're importing both themes in the styles in the bundle regardless).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// using inline webpack loaders for convenience of the example in Code Sandbox
import mainCSS from "!!raw-loader!./styles.css";
import altCSS from "!!raw-loader!./altstyles.css";
// Using helmet to bring the styles into the head (not necessary)
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

console.log(mainCSS);
export default function App() {
  const [showAltStyles, setShowAltStyles] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet>
        <style>{showAltStyles ? altCSS : mainCSS}</style>
      </Helmet>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setShowAltStyles(!showAltStyles)}>
        Toggle Alt Styles
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

An [example Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/style-swapping-4zpd0?file=/src/App.js) with the implementation.

### Option 2: CSS Variables

A more robust option would be to use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and override them using a css class that sets the property. This would require more work to adapt your bootswatch themes.

```css
:root {
  --primary: #FFFFFF;
}

.dark-theme {
  --primary: #000000;
}
```

This option avoids duplicate styles by swapping out the variables defined for each style. If you choose this option you should consider [browser support](https://caniuse.com/css-variables), and whether you're ok with no theming on unsupported browsers.